# How to remove highlighter EditText when clicking off

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have many EditText and when I click a button off I cancel focus from  all but I get the result that it becomes highlighted the first EditText , and I can not take away this highlighter . I want to reset all the initial condition EditExt

```
 private void buttonClick(){

    mTxtFld2.setCursorVisible(false);
    mTxtFld3.setCursorVisible(false);
    mTxtFld4.setCursorVisible(false);
    mTxtFld5.setCursorVisible(false);

    mTxtFld2.clearFocus();
    mTxtFld3.clearFocus();
    mTxtFld4.clearFocus();
    mTxtFld5.clearFocus();

    mTxtFld2.setSelectAllOnFocus(false);
    mTxtFld3.setSelectAllOnFocus(false);
    mTxtFld4.setSelectAllOnFocus(false);
    mTxtFld5.setSelectAllOnFocus(false);

    mTxtFld2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mTxtFld3.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mTxtFld4.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mTxtFld5.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    View v = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if (v == null) return;

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

In xml

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="621dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
            android:id="@+id/EditText2"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:fontFamily="fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_placeholder"
            android:background="@drawable/back" />
```

Comment: You can reset all input focus by hiding the keyboard:getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an hidden focusable layout to set the focus on :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dummy_focus"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

In your offButton action, set the focus on this layout.